# Division by $0$

Tags: arithmetic, infinity

Everyone knows that $(x/y)\times y = x$. So why does $(x/0)\times 0 \ne x$?

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2F0%29*0), it is 'indeterminate'. What does this mean?

Also, are there any other exceptions to that rule?

Comment: Consider $0\times 2=0\times 3=0\times 5$. This is true, but this does not imply the statement $2=3=5$...

Comment: the expression $x/0$ is meaningless. And $(x/y)*y = x$ is only true when $y \ne 0$.

Comment: Another way of putting it: $0\times 2=0$ and $0\times 3=0$. Do you not think that it is unsatisfactory to obtain $0/0=2$ from the first and $0/0=3$ from the second?

Comment: @user774025 why is $x/0$ meaningless - it may come to $\infty$ but why is it meaningless?

Comment: May be this link will help you.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionbyZero.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x/y$ means "the unique number such that $y \cdot (x/y) = x$." If $x$ is any number, does there exist a unique number $a$ such that $0 \cdot a = x\;$?